# JPEG with transparent background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, background, file-format, jpg

My client wants me to supply images for web as JPEG with transparent background. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it possible your client does not know what JPEG means and is using the term as a generic word for image?

Comment: @WGroleau maybe the client is AJA class (Averge Joe - Advanced) that considers JPEG as synonym for bitmaps (a.k.a. the images with pixels).

Comment: Is there a chance to hand them proper `.png` images and if they ask why you did not give them `.jpeg`s you can anser them the format is supported as wide as `jpeg` is and it supports transparency. I think, as WGroleau mentione, they won't notice anything.

Comment: Renaming the file as `image.jpeg.png` might be sufficient.

Answer (score 45):

JPG does not allow transparent backgrounds.

The only thing you can do is have a flat color background that would blend into your website: eg. if your website background is white, then have JPGs created with a white background.

Otherwise you need to consider saving as PNG, which does allow true transparency.

Comment: Is this a good idea to try to set a blending background color since it might not be homogeneous?

Comment: @Amessihel No, but it's the only option if JPG format is indeed required and transparency needs to be simulated.

Answer (score 17):

JPEG doesn't support transparency at all.

Most compatible option is to use PNG, but results in large files for photographs because it is lossless compression.

Another option is to use the new WebP file format which supports both lossless (like PNG) and lossy compression (like JPEG), and allows transparency with both. [Support for WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq#which_web_browsers_natively_support_webp) is relatively good these days, but not yet universal (notably neither Safari nor IE supports it, but Edge does).

Comment: Regarding WebP, I think more notably: Safari currently does not support it at all (mobile nor desktop). That eliminates ~25% of the entire browser market share, obviously including all iPhones.

Comment: [WebP browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp).

Comment: Why one would need transparency in high-resolution photographs?

Comment: @Crowley, consider an "about" page with photographs of the company's staff.

Comment: @Mark I still cannot find reason using transparency there. Proper choice of the shooting background is much neatier way.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 16):

While the JPEG format can't handle transparency itself, it is entirely possible to have transparency using JPEGs with modern browsers. It is, however, complicated. It involves using SVG to create a clipping mask that handles the transparency. With Photoshop, you can do this with the pen tool, and then export to Illustrator, where you can convert the pen tool path into an SVG.

Here is a [more detailed guide](https://css-tricks.com/transparent-jpg-svg/) for how to do so.

> The trick is to make two things:

> - The JPG
> - The clipping

> The JPG is easy enough. Output that right from Photoshop. Optimize.

> Now we can set up the SVG. SVG is happy to take a raster graphic. SVG is known for vector graphics, but it's a very flexible image format.

> ```
> <svg>
>   <image xlink:href="/images/chris.jpg" x="0" y="0">
> </svg>
> ```

> To get the path, we export the path we created with the Pen tool over to Illustrator. Now we have the path over there, and it's easy to export as SVG[.]

> Now we have the path data we need[.] Let's use that  within a  in the SVG we've started. Then also apply that clip path to the :

> ```
> <svg viewBox="0 0 921.17 1409.71">
>   <defs>
>     <clipPath id="chris-clip">
>       <path d="[path data from Illustrator]" />
>     </clipPath>
>   </defs>
>       <image xlink:href="/images/chris.jpg" clip-path="url(#chris-clip)" x="0" y="0" width="921" height="1409">
> </svg>
> ```

Alternatively, here is [a tool that will just convert a PNG into an SVG with embedded JPEGs](http://quasimondo.com/ZorroSVG/). The advantage over WebP is that it will work in Internet Explorer (since version 9) and Safari (since version 3), including on iOS.

That said, the usual standard is indeed to just color the JPEG background to match that of the website, or to use optimized 8-bit PNG, (using a tool like PNGQuant to convert regular 32-bit PNGs).

Comment: In all fairness, SVG with a clipping mask is *not* jpg. And a clipping mask is a level of complexity that may or may not be desired.

Comment: @Scott I agree; it isn't. But I don't read the Question as requiring that. It doesn't say a "JPEG file containing transparency" but just "images for web as JPEG with transparency," which is more ambiguous. Furthermore, even if that is not what the OP or their client meant, I believe that the information in my Answer may be relevant to future readers who search for and find this Question in the future. It's just as valid as including information about WebP or suggesting the use of PNG.

Comment: If you need partial transparency, you should use a mask (which could be a separate grayscale PNG) instead of clipping.

Comment: This is like saying you can drive your car over the ocean... if you put it on a boat. Come on.

Comment: Doing the pen step in Photoshop just to export the path to Illustrator for exporting to SVG seems like a gross misuse of the programs - just do the pen step in Illustrator. That being said, this seems like it both overcomplicates the issue and is too limiting for modern practices (e.g. you can't have partial transparency with this option). If there's flexibility on the image format, then just use PNG. If the source image must be a JPG, then the masking should be done with a greyscale image mask like what Joey suggests. Barring specific needs, those should be the only two reasonable options.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica : agreed, but it's also like answering a question about crossing the ocean from someone who might not have heard about boats; sometimes the exact question people ask is not the exact problem they are trying to solve; the original question *could be* an XY Problem, and this answer provides a good response to a reasonable guess at what 'X' really is

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica What many customers "need" is such solution based on unobtainium physics and handwavium mechanics...

Comment: @Crowley Which is the point at which you sell them a boat instead :)

Comment: @Joey That's exactly what my second link does. Like I said, it's an automated tool that will convert to SVG--the only way that is possible is to convert the alpha layer (which is separate in PNG-32) into a mask.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica My answer just uses the existing web technologies built into the HTML5 spec, which include CSS 3 and SVG 1.1. As such, there is no boat. It's like when someone argues that you can't do something in CSS, and yet someone finds a way. And, frankly, it's a superior solution for lossy transparent images than WebP, since it is more widely supported. You don't want to use WebP without fallback as long as iPhones and iPads don't support it. (And that's assuming you don't care about IE support.) It's bizarre to me that it hasn't caught on, as there is even an automated tool.

Comment: @trlkly The HTML5 spec has nothing to do with JPEG ;)

Comment: @trlkly: I, for one appreciate the answer, and I learned something about SVG and clipping masks (I never thought about trying to use a mask in svg for raster images, but it makes sense). We can argue all day about JPEG, but the other answers offer a non-jpeg answer as well, since the answer to the question *as asked* is "you can't".

Comment: @trlkly A] OP presumably has no real control over how their client implements the JPEG image. If OP comes back saying "you get transparency in the JPEG by using an HTML5/CSS3 SVG mask, the client will likely complain that that is too complicated and they just want an image they can use as-is (which segues to) B] OP's client specifically asked for a JPEG. If they are open to instead receiving an SVG with the mask built-in, then presumably they would be just as open as receiving a PNG that skips all that masking business and just gives you an image with an included alpha channel. Problem solved.

Answer (score 11):

[JPEG 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000) (also known as JP2) is an improved version of the original JPEG format (from 1992) that also has full support for transparency, but it has [abysmal browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=jpeg2000) (only Safari supports it).

I agree with Lucian, just use PNG, it is extremely well-supported, and there are many tools (pngcrush, optipng, pngout...) to compress files. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Optimizing_tools) for a comparison.

In regards to what tylisirn said, I understand the concern about file size, but consider this: it is the norm for web pages to be bloated, these days. However, on the other hand, a fast page load time leaves a good impression on users, and [has a positive effect on SEO](https://www.oncrawl.com/oncrawl-seo-thoughts/page-speed-how-it-impacts-your-seo-and-how-to-improve-it/).

Comment: related: [progressive image rendering](https://blog.codinghorror.com/progressive-image-rendering/)

Comment: @beppe9000 thanks for the link! While reading it I was reminded of how Facebook uses blurry thumbnails as placeholders while it downloads the actual image. It's not really progressive loading, more of a distraction instead of blank space, but the microthumbnails have the advantage of taking a negligible amount of space (~200 bytes). This technique could definitely be applied to PNG, maybe even JPEG if it has support for custom metadata, but I don't think browsers would be interested in implementing it... https://engineering.fb.com/android/the-technology-behind-preview-photos/

Comment: Nice engineering at fb... Well, I think it doesn't scale very well with content served by different entities. Probably WebP is a more appealing alternative. This one is a good read too: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization

Answer (score 3):

You can with PHP and Imagick remove the background dynamically. (remove a fushia color for example).  ~ you create a PNG/GIF  at runtime from JPG (you can cache transparent image in a folder to avoid server overheating)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544467/imagemagick-white-to-transparent-background-while-maintaining-white-object

Comment: A cool option, but probably not relevant as OP is merely providing the image file to a client, not designing and hosting their website's backend for them. As such, the image itself needs to support transparency.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the lossy compression nature of JPEG compression, creating a JPEG with a flat colour background for chroma-keying is not recommended since the colour will bleed into surrounding areas.

Depending on how the images are being used, supplying a greyscale matte image in addition to a standard JPEG may suffice, as in the JEPG format the greyscale component of the image data is stored at a much higher resolution than the colour data.  These would need to be combined using the canvas API or similar.

As others have mentioned, a better solution would be to just use a format like PNG, which naively supports an alpha channel and is browser compatible.

Answer (score 3):

With the advent of CSS3 `mask-image` property, one could provide an external alpha mask image for the JPEGs, thus granting them the alpha channel they lack.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, nice to know! But it doesn't seem to answer the question. It doesn't seem like the OP is directly involved in web development but has hit a wall with a misinformed request from a client.

Comment: Of course. But, for others seeking similar solutions, this might prove useful.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the edge-cases presented in the other answers a JPEG for all practical purposes does not support transparency.

The most common formats which will support transparency are PNG, GIF, and SVG.

If none of these file formats are suitable for the client and a JPEG is required for whatever outlandish reason then you simply need to provide a JPEG for each use-case.

If they are doing a poster then have them tell you the poster color and provide a JPEG with a background to match. If they are simply printing on paper then a white background should be fine. If it will be used on their website then you will need to provide a background suitable for each place used on the website.

Hint: make sure to charge for each use-case

Comment: Including SVG in that list is somewhat misleading, seeing as it's a very different format from the other two.

Comment: @Abion47 Even [IE9 supports it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg). I would say that any printing company worth their salt is going to request an SVG since it will let them blow it up as large as they need.

Comment: You misunderstand my point. An image that started life as a raster image cannot be saved as an SVG in the way that it can be saved as a PNG or GIF. If OP's image was in a vector format originally, then it should absolutely be kept as a vector format for as long as possible. But if it's an image composition (in Photoshop, for example), then the SVG ship has long since sailed unless OP wants to effectively redo the entire project in order to save it as an SVG.

Answer (score 0):

You can create PNG image with transparency and then convert it to SVG containing a color information as JPEG and an alpha channel as a grayscale mask. Here is a tool I wrote to do it https://github.com/igrmk/transpeg

Answer (score -3):

Yes, this is possible.

Just create a clipping path in the Paths panel. When saving the file as a JPEG, Photoshop stores the clipping path in the JPEG metadata section.

Note that the clipping path will only have effect when your client opens the file in Photoshop, not in most other programs, specifically not in web browsers.

Comment: *"My client wants me to supply **images for web** as JPEG"*

Comment: @Scott OTOH, this answer and the JPEG2000 one actually answer the question as written. https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/909/991/48c.jpg

Comment: @JollyJoker No they don't, seeing as OP specifically asked for images regarding their use on the web, so neither Photoshop-specific metadata-based masks nor JPEG-extended image formats with virtually non-existent browser support really address OP's actual needs _as written in the question_.